# How can I parse some inf. from a delimited text file?

Tags: r, parsing, text

I have a text file without delimiters. Row content and length change according to record_type. So, the file content is not a table. I have to read some information from text file. I have a description document about filed meaning. Record types are 0000, 1111, 2222, 3333..... etc. I will parse some special filed from text file. But I can not. For example, how can I get "Standing Charge", "Unit Charge", "Maximum Demand" information and SINGLE, DAY, NIGHT information on records with record_type of 0460?

Thank you very much.

```
0000000000000000000000                    000000000000000000000000000000000000  0000 10/08/2220220810                              
0165239768000012712345                    000000000000000000000000000000000000  111120220713+00001681461+00001330873+00001330873+00000266174+00000000000+00000000000+00001597047+00000084414+00000000000+00000000000+00000000000+0000000000020220727202205012022053100010001D/D                    111111111111111111111              Town Centre                                                                                                                    
0165239768000012712345                    000000000000000000000000000000000000  2222+00000000000+00000000000+00000000000+00000000000             120.00+00001330873+00000266174+00001597047                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          +00001597047Invoice                                 +00000035645M                
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 3333AAAAAAA UK bbbbbbb bbb                    111111111111111111111                                                                                                                                                                                                         N100PROARK UK HOTELS LTD               PROARK UK HOTELS LTD                          
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 44442022050120220531                                                                                                         :      40-05-3044151844                                                                                                         M           
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0460000000000000+0000001519710ANNUAL+00000000031STDG                  +0000004.902200020220401+00000015197Standing charge                    SINGLE                                             31   +4.902220220501
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0460000000000000+0000113443920RS0123+00000033561UNIT                  +0000000.338027020220401+00001134439Unit charge                        DAY                                                31+365.9480320220501
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0460000000000000+0000038248130RS0123+00000012433UNIT                  +0000000.307644020220401+00000382481Unit charge                        NIGHT                                              31+123.3811220220501
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0460000000000000+0000000000040ANNUAL+00000000088MD                    +0000000.000000020220401+00000000000Maximum demand                     SINGLE                                             31+0.000000020220501
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0460000000000000+0000000140230ANNUAL           1MOP1                  +0000000.000000020220401+00000001402Meter Operator Charge              SINGLE                                             31   +0.452120220501
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0460000000000000+0000000254850ANNUAL           1COMM                  +0000000.000000020220401+00000002548Communications Line Charge         SINGLE                                             31    +0.82220220501
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0460000000000000+0000000007170ANNUAL+00000000031SAG                   +0000000.023020020220401+00000000071Settlement agency fee              SINGLE                                             31  +0.0230220220501
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0460+00000032587+0000000000040ANNUAL+00000000288AVAL                  +0000001.131500020220401+00000032587Agreed Capacity Charge             SINGLE                                             31   +10.51220220501
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0461           MD000000000000       91.25000001KVA   +00000000091MDKVA N 101457289614700845074SINGLE             20220531                                      20220501        
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0461           RI000000000000     11451.1000001KVARH +00000011451REAP  N 101457289614700845074RCTIMP             20220531                                      20220501        
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0461           MD000000000000        88.2000001KW    +00000000088MD    N 101457289614700845074SINGLE             20220531                                      20220501        
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0461           HH000000000000     33560.6000001KWH   +00000033561UNIT  N 101457289614700845074DAY                20220531                                      20220501        
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0461           HH000000000000     12432.6000001KWH   +00000012433UNIT  N 101457289614700845074NIGHT              20220531                                      20220501        
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0470xxxx20220501Power factor for this site is  0.970298                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 0470   713Reconciliation Payments                                                         
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 5555     45993.20       0          0.775+000000356450       
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 66661+0000133087320.00 +00000266174COMMERCIAL          
0165239768000012712345                    016523976800001271234520220713220500A 7777        +000000000+000000000+001330873                  00+00000000000
016523976800001271234599999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999  8888000001+00001597047000021
999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999  9999000001000001+00001681461000024
```

I have to base record_type.

Comment: It seems this is exactly what [`read.fwf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.fwf.html) is intended to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using the test data in the Note at the end we read in the data giving L, extract the record type which in this case is the first character and then split the lines by record type.  Then use Read to read each record type separately.  If your fields are fixed fields the Read function will need to check the type and then issue the appropriate read.fwf call.

```
L <- readLines("testfile.dat")
rectype <- substr(L, 1, 1)
s <- split(L, rectype)
Read <- function(rectype, lines) read.table(text = lines)
Map(Read, names(s), s)
```

giving this named list of data frames:

```
$`1`
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  1  4  5

$`2`
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  2  4  5  6  7
2  2  7  8  9  9
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "1 2 3
1 4 5
2 4 5 6 7
2 7 8 9 9
"
cat(Lines, file = "testfile.dat")
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestions step by step with your data and my data. But for the last command I lived a problem.

Comment: You likely made an error in extracting the type or defining a version of Read appropriate to your data.

Comment: The content of the data changes according to the record type. I have to read the record type differently for 460 or 0052 etc. I don't know how to do it in the same command. I only read the data with record type 460 with read.fwf, but I could not do it in all data.   dd <- read.fwf(
    file=file.choose(),
        widths=c(10, 9, 4, 9, 4, 9, 4, 9, 4))  # just example

Comment: In Read you need to use if statements with the rectype to run the appropriate read.fwf statement.

Comment: Lines <- "the example data I sent before
"
cat(Lines, file = "test.dat")
M <- readLines("test.dat")
M
rectype <- substr(M, 81, 84)
s <- split(M, rectype)
s
Read <- function(rectype, lines) read.table(text = lines)
Map(Read, names(s), s)

Comment: You need to rewrite Read to be appropriate to your data.

Comment: Lines <- "1234
+ 1457
+ 245678
+ 278995
+ 3111111
+ "
> cat(Lines, file = "testfile.dat") 
> L <- readLines("testfile.dat")
> L
[1] "1234"    "1457"    "245678"  "278995"  "3111111"
> rectype <- substr(L, 1, 1)
> s <- split(L, rectype)
> s
$`1`
[1] "1234" "1457"

$`2`
[1] "245678" "278995"

$`3`
[1] "3111111"

> substr(s,1,3)
[1] "c(\"" "c(\"" "311" 
>

Comment: I want to take record ID, after I use these results in my if clause. But output is not returning correctly.

Comment: I want to take record ID, after I use these results in my if clause. But output is not returning correctly. This is from your example. From my data returning  [1] "0000" "0050" "0051" "0100" "0101" "0A 0" "0A 0" "0A 0" "0A 0" "1455" "1460" "1500" "2000". Rows with record number 460, 461 are more than one. For just 0460 returning one wrong value 0A 0 and 0461, 0470, 0860 same.